# How to add numeric filter to Algolia ais-instantsearch component in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular6, algolia

I am using the [ais-instantsearch](https://community.algolia.com/angular-instantsearch/) component of Algolia to search and show results, in Angular.

Currently, this is my code,

```
<ais-instantsearch [config]="config">
    <ais-hits>
        ...
    </ais-hits>
</ais-instantsearch>
```

Now my question is, how to add numericFilter to this search request?

For example, I want to return all hits with attribute `is_simple=1`. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am aware of the following three options, depending on how often the filter should change.

**1. searchParameters in configure Widget**

```
<ais-instantsearch [config]="config">
  <ais-configure [searchParameters]="{ filters: 'is_simple=1' }">
  </ais-configure>
  ...
</ais-instantsearch>
```

You can dynamically edit the filter, which will cause the search to be triggered.

Source: https://community.algolia.com/angular-instantsearch/widgets/configure.html

**2. searchParameters in instantSearch Widget**

You can add a filter directly in the config of the instantSearch widget, as suggested earlier by Ajay. Use this option if it is a permanent filter.

Source: https://community.algolia.com/angular-instantsearch/widgets/instantsearch.html

**3. searchFunction in instantSearch Widget**

```
<ais-instantsearch [config]="{
          apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
          appId: 'XXXXXXX',
          indexName: 'test_index',
          searchFunction: searchFunction }" >
...
</ais-instantsearch>
```

The searchFunction hook is called whenever a search is triggered, giving you the [AlgoliaSearchHelper](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-helper-js#helper-cheatsheet:).

```
   searchFunction(helper) {
     helper.addNumericRefinement('is_simple', '=', '1');
     helper.search();
   }
```

Make sure to actually trigger the search. Use this option if you want to edit the filter with every search.

Source: https://community.algolia.com/angular-instantsearch/widgets/instantsearch.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to expand the `config` to include `searchParameters` as they describe in the [docs](https://community.algolia.com/angular-instantsearch/widgets/instantsearch.html#code-example) - but also note it is [recommended](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/numericFilters/?language=javascript#how-to-use) to use basic `filters` over `numericFilters`:

```
<ais-instantsearch
  [config]="{
    apiKey: '6be0576ff61c053d5f9a3225e2a90f76',
    appId: 'latency',
    indexName: 'instant_search',
    searchParameters: {
        filters: 'is_simple=1'
    }
  }"
>
  <ais-hits>
    ...
  </ais-hits>
</ais-instantsearch>
```